# GetView method getting called after changing focus [Android]

Tags: android

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551855/arrayadapters-getview-method-getting-called-automatically-on-edittext-focus-e) asked by "vbjain", but answer that are given are not satisfactory for me.

I am also facing same problem, I have a huge list where i need to do extensive calculation in `getView()` which are unavoidable, my list contains live data which gets generated at the time of displaying list, so i can't avoid these calculation other than doing them in `getView` function.

I don't know why `getView` method is getting called when i am switching focus from/to list view, cause of `getView` is getting called at the time of changing the focus and i am doing calculations in `getView` my application gets stuck for 2-3 seconds and then it switches focus from/to list view.

Is there any way by which we can avoid this behavior of list view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list view behaves the way it does largely for performance reasons, I can't recommend [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA) video enough for people working with list views, Romain Guy explains everything clearly and concisely. If you want your list view to perform, follow his advice.

Comment: I have used all the guide lines provided by Romain Guy while implementing the list, but still i am facing this problem.

Comment: If you need to do intensive calculations you should probably not do it on the UI thread anyway. Would it work for your app to display some sort of loading view in the list view, while an async task gets the required data, and then update the list view once the data is available? Or perhaps display the latest data in the list view while you get updates int he background? So your get view logic would simply be checking if its data is available, and deciding what to display based on that.